Internal vs External in type theory
I'm learning type theory, and at one point in the HoTT book, is mentionned "external" constructions. I was wondering what precisely means internal/external in type thoery.

See https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/101440/internal-vs-external-statement-in-homotopy-type-theory

Thanks ! I appreciate it !

Internal constructions are expressed in the language of type theory itself. External constructions are expressed in the metalanguage, i.e. the language we use to formalise type theory. For example, $a : A$ ("$a$ has type $A$") is an external judgement.
Some judgements can be internalised. For example, judgemental equality $\Gamma \vdash a \equiv b : A$ is internalised by the identity types $\Gamma \vdash p : a =_A b$. The two notions may or may not agree (this is the difference between extensional and intensional type theory).
The book mentions that setoids are (usually) external constructions because you consider a type equipped with a pseudo-equivalence relation. By contrast, HoTT can internally talk about $\infty$-groupoids, because every type automatically comes with the structure of an $\infty$-groupoid.

Thanks ! I'm still partly confused. What is the language used to formalise type theory, ? And why is $a:A$ an external judgement ?

For formalising type theory, you can use all sorts of meta languages. From mathematical English to formal set theory or type theory itself, there are many options. -- It is an external judgment because you cannot internally pose the question "what is the type of this $a$?". Just from looking at the term itself, how its built from its constituents, you (as an external observer of the term) can tell its type. Unlike determining whether a given type is inhabited at all, what the type of a given term is is never an open research problem, but a matter of direct computation.
